# Python Error When Accessing JSON Data From AngularJS POST

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, post

I am trying to send data to a python script via POST but unable to read it.  The UI is in AngularJS.  I have seen similar questions but they are either not using AngularJS or not using POST.

The Angular code:

```
$scope.send = function(){

        $data = {
            "tableData":$scope.personsSelected
        }

        $postData = JSON.stringify($data);
        Services.post('testbed.cgi', $postData);
    }
```

Python Code:

```
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
print json.dumps(formData)
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: FieldStorage(None, None, []) is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried setting the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded but to no avail.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the data you are trying to send as JSON. Whats the data you are trying to send? Is it a Python object? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) may help you. Are those plain strings? Dictionary? Do they have invalid characters? You can use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to check validity.

Comment: javascript array, stringified